# Can not receive response from PUT & DELETE methods with Nginx remote server

Tags: laravel, api, nginx

When I put the laravel project on the host , i faced a problem.

i Can not receive response from laravel api (only api)  in PUT & DELETE methods with Nginx  remote server.

what is the problem?

Comment: Do you receive no response at all? Not even a 404 or 500?

Comment: postman says: Could not get any response.
i do not receive any  response without status code into postman in put & delete method. the other methods like get , post, ...  are ok.  
@RMcLeod